# How to fix undefined reference to v8 error?

Tags: c++, node.js, compiler-errors, cmake, clion

I'm trying to configure and build a sample of node.js addon. The sample was taken from node.js documentation and the source code can be found here

https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-examples/tree/master/8_passing_wrapped/node_0.12

When I try to compile this in CLion (on Ubuntu 14.04) or when I use node-gyp to build it I've got some errors:

```
    /home/smorzhov/Documents/clion-2016.1/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /home/smorzhov/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/test4-94ee4803/94ee4803/Debug --target all -- -j 4
[ 25%] Linking CXX executable test4
CMakeFiles/test4.dir/myobject.cpp.o: In function `demo::MyObject::Init(v8::Isolate*)':
/home/smorzhov/ClionProjects/test4/test4/myobject.cpp:26: undefined reference to `v8::FunctionTemplate::New(v8::Isolate*, void (*)(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&), v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Signature>, int)'
/home/smorzhov/ClionProjects/test4/test4/myobject.cpp:27: undefined reference to `v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate*, char const*, v8::String::NewStringType, int)'
/home/smorzhov/ClionProjects/test4/test4/myobject.cpp:27: undefined reference to `v8::FunctionTemplate::SetClassName(v8::Local<v8::String>)'
/home/smorzhov/ClionProjects/test4/test4/myobject.cpp:28: undefined reference to `v8::FunctionTemplate::InstanceTemplate()'
/home/smorzhov/ClionProjects/test4/test4/myobject.cpp:28: undefined reference to `v8::ObjectTemplate::SetInternalFieldCount(int)'
/home/smorzhov/ClionProjects/test4/test4/myobject.cpp:30: undefined reference to `v8::FunctionTemplate::GetFunction()'
/home/smorzhov/ClionProjects/test4/test4/myobject.cpp:30: undefined reference to `demo::MyObject::constructor'
CMakeFiles/test4.dir/myobject.cpp.o: In function `v8::PersistentBase<v8::Function>::Reset()':
/usr/include/node/v8.h:7224: undefined reference to `v8::V8::DisposeGlobal(v8::internal::Object**)'
CMakeFiles/test4.dir/myobject.cpp.o: In function `v8::PersistentBase<v8::Function>::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Function*)':
/usr/include/node/v8.h:7176: undefined reference to `v8::V8::GlobalizeReference(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Object**)'
CMakeFiles/test4.dir/myobject.cpp.o: In function `Reset<v8::Function>':
/usr/include/node/v8.h:7235: undefined reference to `demo::MyObject::constructor'
CMakeFiles/test4.dir/myobject.cpp.o: In function `demo::MyObject::New(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)':
/home/smorzhov/ClionProjects/test4/test4/myobject.cpp:38: undefined reference to `v8::Value::NumberValue() const'
CMakeFiles/test4.dir/myobject.cpp.o: In function `v8::Local<v8::Function>::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::PersistentBase<v8::Function> const&)':
/usr/include/node/v8.h:7124: undefined reference to `demo::MyObject::constructor'
CMakeFiles/test4.dir/myobject.cpp.o: In function `v8::Local<v8::Function>::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Function*)':
/usr/include/node/v8.h:7134: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::CreateHandle(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Object*)'
CMakeFiles/test4.dir/myobject.cpp.o: In function `demo::MyObject::New(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)':
/home/smorzhov/ClionProjects/test4/test4/myobject.cpp:47: undefined reference to `v8::Function::NewInstance(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const'
CMakeFiles/test4.dir/myobject.cpp.o: In function `v8::Local<v8::Function>::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::PersistentBase<v8::Function> const&)':
/usr/include/node/v8.h:7124: undefined reference to `demo::MyObject::constructor'
CMakeFiles/test4.dir/myobject.cpp.o: In function `v8::Local<v8::Function>::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Function*)':
/usr/include/node/v8.h:7134: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::CreateHandle(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Object*)'
CMakeFiles/test4.dir/myobject.cpp.o: In function `demo::MyObject::NewInstance(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)':
/home/smorzhov/ClionProjects/test4/test4/myobject.cpp:57: undefined reference to `v8::Function::NewInstance(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const'
CMakeFiles/test4.dir/myobject.cpp.o: In function `ClearWeak<void>':
/usr/include/node/v8.h:7298: undefined reference to `v8::V8::ClearWeak(v8::internal::Object**)'
CMakeFiles/test4.dir/myobject.cpp.o: In function `v8::PersistentBase<v8::Object>::Reset()':
/usr/include/node/v8.h:7224: undefined reference to `v8::V8::DisposeGlobal(v8::internal::Object**)'
CMakeFiles/test4.dir/myobject.cpp.o: In function `node::ObjectWrap::Wrap(v8::Local<v8::Object>)':
/usr/include/node/node_object_wrap.h:56: undefined reference to `v8::Object::InternalFieldCount()'
/usr/include/node/node_object_wrap.h:57: undefined reference to `v8::Object::SetAlignedPointerInInternalField(int, void*)'
/usr/include/node/node_object_wrap.h:58: undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::GetCurrent()'
CMakeFiles/test4.dir/myobject.cpp.o: In function `v8::PersistentBase<v8::Object>::Reset()':
/usr/include/node/v8.h:7224: undefined reference to `v8::V8::DisposeGlobal(v8::internal::Object**)'
CMakeFiles/test4.dir/myobject.cpp.o: In function `v8::PersistentBase<v8::Object>::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Object*)':
/usr/include/node/v8.h:7176: undefined reference to `v8::V8::GlobalizeReference(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Object**)'
CMakeFiles/test4.dir/myobject.cpp.o: In function `SetWeak<v8::Object, node::ObjectWrap>':
/usr/include/node/v8.h:7257: undefined reference to `v8::V8::MakeWeak(v8::internal::Object**, void*, void (*)(v8::WeakCallbackData<v8::Value, void> const&))'
CMakeFiles/test4.dir/myobject.cpp.o: In function `ClearWeak<void>':
/usr/include/node/v8.h:7298: undefined reference to `v8::V8::ClearWeak(v8::internal::Object**)'
CMakeFiles/test4.dir/myobject.cpp.o: In function `node::ObjectWrap::WeakCallback(v8::WeakCallbackData<v8::Object, node::ObjectWrap> const&)':
/usr/include/node/node_object_wrap.h:101: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::HandleScope(v8::Isolate*)'
CMakeFiles/test4.dir/myobject.cpp.o: In function `v8::Local<v8::Object>::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Object*)':
/usr/include/node/v8.h:7134: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::CreateHandle(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Object*)'
CMakeFiles/test4.dir/myobject.cpp.o: In function `v8::PersistentBase<v8::Object>::Reset()':
/usr/include/node/v8.h:7224: undefined reference to `v8::V8::DisposeGlobal(v8::internal::Object**)'
CMakeFiles/test4.dir/myobject.cpp.o: In function `node::ObjectWrap::WeakCallback(v8::WeakCallbackData<v8::Object, node::ObjectWrap> const&)':
/usr/include/node/node_object_wrap.h:108: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope()'
/usr/include/node/node_object_wrap.h:108: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope()'
CMakeFiles/test4.dir/addon.cpp.o: In function `demo::Add(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)':
/home/smorzhov/ClionProjects/test4/test4/addon.cpp:27: undefined reference to `v8::Number::New(v8::Isolate*, double)'
CMakeFiles/test4.dir/addon.cpp.o: In function `demo::InitAll(v8::Local<v8::Object>)':
/home/smorzhov/ClionProjects/test4/test4/addon.cpp:31: undefined reference to `v8::Object::GetIsolate()'
CMakeFiles/test4.dir/addon.cpp.o: In function `_register_addon':
/home/smorzhov/ClionProjects/test4/test4/addon.cpp:37: undefined reference to `node_module_register'
CMakeFiles/test4.dir/addon.cpp.o: In function `v8::Value::ToObject() const':
/usr/include/node/v8.h:7778: undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::GetCurrent()'
/usr/include/node/v8.h:7778: undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::GetCurrentContext()'
/usr/include/node/v8.h:7779: undefined reference to `v8::Value::ToObject(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const'
CMakeFiles/test4.dir/addon.cpp.o: In function `demo::MyObject* node::ObjectWrap::Unwrap<demo::MyObject>(v8::Local<v8::Object>)':
/usr/include/node/node_object_wrap.h:29: undefined reference to `v8::Object::InternalFieldCount()'
CMakeFiles/test4.dir/addon.cpp.o: In function `v8::Object::GetAlignedPointerFromInternalField(int)':
/usr/include/node/v8.h:7636: undefined reference to `v8::Object::SlowGetAlignedPointerFromInternalField(int)'
CMakeFiles/test4.dir/addon.cpp.o: In function `void node::NODE_SET_METHOD<v8::Local<v8::Object> >(v8::Local<v8::Object> const&, char const*, void (*)(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&))':
/usr/include/node/node.h:239: undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::GetCurrent()'
/usr/include/node/node.h:240: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::HandleScope(v8::Isolate*)'
/usr/include/node/node.h:242: undefined reference to `v8::FunctionTemplate::New(v8::Isolate*, void (*)(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&), v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Signature>, int)'
/usr/include/node/node.h:243: undefined reference to `v8::FunctionTemplate::GetFunction()'
/usr/include/node/node.h:244: undefined reference to `v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate*, char const*, v8::String::NewStringType, int)'
/usr/include/node/node.h:245: undefined reference to `v8::Function::SetName(v8::Local<v8::String>)'
/usr/include/node/node.h:246: undefined reference to `v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)'
/usr/include/node/node.h:246: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope()'
/usr/include/node/node.h:246: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [test4] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/test4.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Maybe it is important, the IDE don't understand 

    `#include node.h`  

and I have to change it to `#include node/node.h`

It seems, that compiler sees only node and v8 headers and cannot find their sources.

Can somebody help me to fix that? How to make compiler to see node and v8 sources?

PS. My CmakeLists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(test4)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES addon.cpp main.cpp myobject.cpp myobject.h)
add_executable(test4 ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Comment: Did you try to follow [README](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-examples/blob/master/README.md)?

Comment: Remove header file from **${SOURCES_FILES}**. Try to change the order of the file chain, something like this: **addon.cpp myobject.cpp main.cpp**. Also since you are in unix world, try to use **gnu++11** as your c++11 param.

Comment: It doesn't fix the problem

Comment: Maybe it is important, the IDE don't understand  #include node.h  and I have to change it to #include node/node.h

Comment: @Joel, or even better , replace `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` with [`CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.html), as CMake >= 3.1 is used.

Comment: Nothing changes. It seems, that compiler sees only node and v8 headers and cannot find their sources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the README and use `node-gyp` with the `-v` flag, you can see that compilation looks like this:

`g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=addon' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' -I/home/yannick/.node-gyp/5.9.0/include/node -I/home/yannick/.node-gyp/5.9.0/src -I/home/yannick/.node-gyp/5.9.0/deps/uv/include -I/home/yannick/.node-gyp/5.9.0/deps/v8/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -std=gnu++0x -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/addon/myobject.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/addon/myobject.o ../myobject.cc`

So it's a tad more complex that just specifying a few sources : there are several include dirs to be used, that seems specific to the node version you are running, and include an external dependency (`libuv`)

Why don't you use the build methods suggested by the README ?